# Is it necessary to implement both Content-Security-Policy and X-Content-Type-Options for ensuring the security of a website?

Tags: web-application, appsec, content-security-policy

Is it necessary to implement both **Content-Security-Policy** and **X-Content-Type-Options** for ensuring the security of a website?

Comment: Those are very different options. Why do you ask? Are you actually asking about CORB? https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/services/network/cross_origin_read_blocking_explainer.md#determining-whether-a-response-is-corb_protected

Answer (score 0):

Both headers are defense-in-depth type headers, so "neccessary" might be a bit strong.

But both headers do have a purpose, and they do not overlap. The two problems I can think of:

- CSP bypass
- XSSI (this is probably the more important one)

Imagine a CSP such as this:

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src http://example.com"
```

`example.com` also has an XSS vulnerability.

Additionally, `example.com` allows file uploads, but just `.txt` files. That seems secure(-ish), but it isn't. Injecting `<script src=http://example.com/uploads/x.txt></script>` will work.

If the request which returns the `x.txt` file includes `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff`, that payload will not work. So in this example, the header does add additional defense-in-depth.

[This article](https://www.coalfire.com/the-coalfire-blog/mime-sniffing-in-browsers-and-the-security) goes into a bit more detail.

---

Additionally, you can run into XSSI problems if non-javascript files contain sensitive data which also parses as javascript. One example would eg be a config file `config.txt` with the content:

```
password="supersecure"
```

It's only accessible to authenticated users. But it can be read out by a remote attacker across origins with the following code:

```
<script src=http://vuln.com/config.txt></script>
<script>alert(password)</script>
```

Again, a nosniff header would prevent that.